# how I can add 2 auto-increment columns in the same table in the laravel database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to know if I can add 2 auto-increment columns in the same table in laravel? but the second has different value to start with it?

---

### uniID I want to start from 43600000,

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table){
$table->increments('id');
$table->increments('uniID');
$table->integer('student_id');
$table->timestamps();});
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE students AUTO_INCREMENT = 43600000;");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create two auto increment column in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824439/how-to-create-two-auto-increment-column-in-mysql) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: Rather than duplicate data in the database - your second field can just be output as the id+43600000.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doesn't support this because databases don't generally support it.  The `increments()` and `bigIncrements()` column types cannot be used multiple times in the same table `Schema` and will fail on create:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "students" has more than one primary key
```

But if `uniId` will always be 43600000 larger than `id`, you can use a computed attribute in Eloquent:

```php
class Student
{
    public function getUniIdAttribute()
    {
        return $this->id + 43600000;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in your controllers or Blade templates:

```php
>>> $user = Student::first()
=> App\Student{#3078
     id: 1,
     ...
   }
>>> $student->uniId
=> 43600001
```

The downside to this approach is that you won't be able to use `uniId` as a foreign key in other tables.

Comment: can you write your email or anything to allow me to connect with you?

Comment: @shrooq feel free to comment here if anything is unclear.  or you can ask a new question :)

Comment: how I can add unique id ? dont say uuid becous it is too long

Comment: @shrooq the only thing truly unique is your auto-incrementing primary key.  otherwise you could generate a hash from something else unique to the student, like an email address

Comment: @shrooq or go with a slug-based approach based off first and last names and a number.  similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859974/laravel-how-to-properly-generate-unique-slugs-from-article-titles